# How to update state from firebase auth in my react application

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, formik

I can successfully login with the below code, however I don't believe react is receiving any auth data back form google to update the current user in react.

I know I am missing something here but I don't know what. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import * as Yup from 'yup'
import clsx from 'clsx'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {useFormik} from 'formik'
import {getUserByToken, login} from '../core/_requests'
import {toAbsoluteUrl} from '../../../../_metronic/helpers'
import {useAuth} from '../core/Auth'
import {
  auth,
  db,
  signInWithGoogle,
  logInWithEmailAndPassword,
  registerWithEmailAndPassword,
  sendPasswordReset,
  logout,
} from "../../../../firebase.js";
import { Firestore } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';



const loginSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  email: Yup.string()
    .email('Wrong email format')
    .min(3, 'Minimum 3 symbols')
    .max(50, 'Maximum 50 symbols')
    .required('Email is required'),
  password: Yup.string()
    .min(3, 'Minimum 3 symbols')
    .max(50, 'Maximum 50 symbols')
    .required('Password is required'),
})

const initialValues = {
  email: 'admin@demo.com',
  password: 'demo',
}

/*
  Formik+YUP+Typescript:
  https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/tutorial#getfieldprops
  https://medium.com/@maurice.de.beijer/yup-validation-and-typescript-and-formik-6c342578a20e
*/


export function Login() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues,
    validationSchema: loginSchema,
    onSubmit: async (values, { setStatus, setSubmitting }) => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        await logInWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password);
        setLoading(false);
        navigate('/dashboard');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        setSubmitting(false);
        setLoading(false);
        //setStatus(error.message);
      }
    },
  });

  return (
    <form
      className='form w-100'
      onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}
      noValidate
      id='kt_login_signin_form'
    >
      {/* begin::Heading */}
      <div className='text-center mb-10'>
        <h1 className='text-dark mb-3'>Sign In to Web Construct</h1>
        <div className='text-gray-400 fw-bold fs-4'>
          New Here?{' '}
          <Link to='/auth/registration' className='link-primary fw-bolder'>
            Create an Account
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* begin::Heading */}

      {formik.status ? (
        <div className='mb-lg-15 alert alert-danger'>
          <div className='alert-text font-weight-bold'>{formik.status}</div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className='mb-10 bg-light-info p-8 rounded'>
          <div className='text-info'>
            Use account <strong>admin@demo.com</strong> and password <strong>demo</strong> to
            continue.
          </div>
        </div>
      )}

      {/* begin::Form group */}
      <div className='fv-row mb-10'>
        <label className='form-label fs-6 fw-bolder text-dark'>Email</label>
        <input
          placeholder='Email'
          {...formik.getFieldProps('email')}
          className={clsx(
            'form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid',
            {'is-invalid': formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email},
            {
              'is-valid': formik.touched.email && !formik.errors.email,
            }
          )}
          type='email'
          name='email'
          autoComplete='off'
        />
        {formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email && (
          <div className='fv-plugins-message-container'>
            <span role='alert'>{formik.errors.email}</span>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      {/* end::Form group */}

      {/* begin::Form group */}
      <div className='fv-row mb-10'>
        <div className='d-flex justify-content-between mt-n5'>
          <div className='d-flex flex-stack mb-2'>
            {/* begin::Label */}
            <label className='form-label fw-bolder text-dark fs-6 mb-0'>Password</label>
            {/* end::Label */}
            {/* begin::Link */}
            <Link
              to='/auth/forgot-password'
              className='link-primary fs-6 fw-bolder'
              style={{marginLeft: '5px'}}
            >
              Forgot Password ?
            </Link>
            {/* end::Link */}
          </div>
        </div>
        <input
          type='password'
          autoComplete='off'
          {...formik.getFieldProps('password')}
          className={clsx(
            'form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid',
            {
              'is-invalid': formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password,
            },
            {
              'is-valid': formik.touched.password && !formik.errors.password,
            }
          )}
        />
        {formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password && (
          <div className='fv-plugins-message-container'>
            <div className='fv-help-block'>
              <span role='alert'>{formik.errors.password}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      {/* end::Form group */}

      {/* begin::Action */}
      <div className='text-center'>
        <button
          
          type='submit'
          id='kt_sign_in_submit'
          className='btn btn-lg btn-primary w-100 mb-5 '
          disabled={formik.isSubmitting || !formik.isValid}
        >
          {!loading && <span className='indicator-label'>Continue</span>}
          {loading && (
            <span className='indicator-progress' style={{display: 'block'}}>
              Please wait...
              <span className='spinner-border spinner-border-sm align-middle ms-2'></span>
            </span>
          )}
        </button>

        {/* begin::Separator */}
        <div className='text-center text-muted text-uppercase fw-bolder mb-5'>or</div>
        {/* end::Separator */}

        {/* begin::Google link */}
        <a className='btn btn-flex flex-center btn-light btn-lg w-100 mb-5'>
          <img
            alt='Logo'
            src={toAbsoluteUrl('/media/svg/brand-logos/google-icon.svg')}
            className='h-20px me-3'
          />
          Continue with Google
        </a>
        {/* end::Google link */}

        {/* begin::Google link */}
        <a href='#' className='btn btn-flex flex-center btn-light btn-lg w-100 mb-5'>
          <img
            alt='Logo'
            src={toAbsoluteUrl('/media/svg/brand-logos/facebook-4.svg')}
            className='h-20px me-3'
          />
          Continue with Facebook
        </a>
        {/* end::Google link */}

        {/* begin::Google link */}
        <a href='#' className='btn btn-flex flex-center btn-light btn-lg w-100'>
          <img
            alt='Logo'
            src={toAbsoluteUrl('/media/svg/brand-logos/apple-black.svg')}
            className='h-20px me-3'
          />
          Continue with Apple
        </a>
        {/* end::Google link */}
      </div>
      {/* end::Action */}
    </form>
  )
}
```

Should firebase be sending back a token or something similar that is saved in the form of a cookie, or am I way off base?

My firebase.js

```
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import {
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  getAuth,
  signInWithPopup,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  sendPasswordResetEmail,
  signOut,
} from "firebase/auth";
import {
  getFirestore,
  query,
  getDocs,
  collection,
  where,
  addDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
const firebaseConfig = {
    
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider);
    const user = res.user;
    const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("uid", "==", user.uid));
    const docs = await getDocs(q);
    if (docs.docs.length === 0) {
      await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
        uid: user.uid,
        name: user.displayName,
        authProvider: "google",
        email: user.email,
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    alert(err.message);
  }
};
const logInWithEmailAndPassword = async (email, password) => {
  try {
    await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    alert(err.message);
  }
};
const registerWithEmailAndPassword = async (name, email, password) => {
  try {
    const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    const user = res.user;
    await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
      uid: user.uid,
      name,
      authProvider: "local",
      email,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    alert(err.message);
  }
};
const sendPasswordReset = async (email) => {
  try {
    await sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email);
    alert("Password reset link sent!");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    alert(err.message);
  }
};
const logout = () => {
  signOut(auth);
};
export {
  auth,
  db,
  signInWithGoogle,
  logInWithEmailAndPassword,
  registerWithEmailAndPassword,
  sendPasswordReset,
  logout,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have to show us what's happening in your `firebase.js` where you're handling the auth.

From what i'm seeing right now, you're missing the firebase hooks that track your auth state - `getAuth` and `onAuthStateChanged`

Refer to docs here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_a_users_profile

Example of how you might do it in `firebase.js`

```js
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// this gets the FirebaseAuth object
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

try {
    // Here you are passing it the auth object when you sign in
    const res = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);

    // And you get the user returned from the successful authentication
    const { user } = res;
  } catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof Error) {
      console.error(err);
      alert(err.message);
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

Outside of `firebase.js`, for example in your current component:

> For each of your app's pages that need information about the signed-in
> user, attach an observer to the global authentication object. This
> observer gets called whenever the user's sign-in state changes.
>
> Attach the observer using the onAuthStateChanged method. When a user
> successfully signs in, you can get information about the user in the
> observer.

```js
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();

// This observes and tracks the state of auth in your application
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    const uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

This should be the missing link between firebase and your React side of things - then you can handle it however you need on this side once you've connected the dots.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've added my firebase.js file above.

Comment: So, in your component, use the `onAuthStateChanged` hook to track your auth state in the last example of my answer

Comment: Your `firebase.js` looks right (as far as `signInWithEmailAndPassword` at least), so your login ought to be successful - in your `login.js` just add in the code in my last example, and that's how you get the authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the return value of this function call
`logInWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password)`!

Based on the response, you either authenticate the user and save the token that's sent or do not authenticate the user.